# What is the purpose of libgif file in DLIB?

Tags: python, c++, computer-vision, dlib

I encountered a problem while installing dlib. I came across this solution https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2358 where it is mentioned that a file called libgif is broken.

Can someone please explain what is this file? What's its purpose? How can it get broken?

**UPDATE** : The solution provided really did solve the problem. But I can't understand what the problem was in the first place.

Comment: you ought to discuss that in the issue you link to. nobody here is as qualified to answer as the library's author.

Comment: Okay I will do that. Will post here if I get a comprehensive response.

Answer (score 1):

[libgif](https://giflib.sourceforge.net/) is a library for reading and writing GIF files.

Though I don’t know dlib, one can presume that it uses libgif to read and/or write GIF files, just like any other package and tool out there that uses giflib (which is many more than you think). So we can assume that dlib will not be able to read and/or write GIF files if you disable linking to this library.